# Error: Couldn't find a drawer. Is your component inside a drawer navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, navigation-drawer

```
    interface MainContainerProps {
    
        header?: ToolbarProps,
        props?: any,
        children?: ReactNode
    
    }
    
    const MainContainer: React.FC<MainContainerProps> = ({ header, props, children }) => {
    
        const [slideDrawer, setSlideDrawer] = useState(false);
    
    
        const drawerProgress = useDrawerProgress()
    
        const screenStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            const scaleY = interpolate(/*sv.value*/drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [1, 0.8], {
                extrapolateRight: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
            });
    
            const borderRadius = interpolate(/*sv.value*/drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [1, 20], {
                extrapolateRight: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
            });
    
            const animatedStyle = { borderRadius, transform: [{ scaleY }] };
            console.log('HERE CALLED : ' + scaleY);
            return {
                transform: [
                    {
                        scaleY,
                    },
                ],
            };
        });
    
        return (<Animated.View> 
    ...
    </Animated.View>)
```

**In this I want to use animation which is present in (<Animation.View></Animation.View>) which is my mainContainer. I am getting error because of using useDrawerProgress() inside this page. And all the screens which are wrapped using this mainContainer. What needs to be done to apply drawer animation to those screens ?**